# TagSpecifications with requestSpotInstances UnexpectedParameter with aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to add a tag to my AWS Spot Request. But it has returned me `{ UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'TagSpecifications' found in params.LaunchSpecification`.
I have followed [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#requestSpotInstances-property), and I have already tried to move this code out of LaunchSpecification, but the error persists.

```js
  const params = {
    InstanceCount: 1,
    LaunchSpecification: {
      ImageId: config.aws.instanceAMI,
      KeyName: 'backoffice',
      InstanceType: config.aws.instanceType,
      SecurityGroupIds: [config.aws.instanceSecurityGroupId],
      TagSpecifications: [{
        ResourceType: 'instance',
        Tags: [{
          Key: 'Type',
          Value: 'Mongo-Dump',
        }],
      }],
      BlockDeviceMappings: [{
        DeviceName: '/dev/xvda',
        Ebs: {
          DeleteOnTermination: true,
          SnapshotId: 'snap-06e838ce2a80337a4',
          VolumeSize: 50,
          VolumeType: 'gp2',
          Encrypted: false,
        },
      }],
      IamInstanceProfile: {
        Name: config.aws.instanceProfileIAMName,
      },
      Placement: {
        AvailabilityZone: `${config.aws.region}a`,
      },
    },
    SpotPrice: config.aws.instancePrice,
    Type: 'one-time',
  };

  return ec2.requestSpotInstances(params).promise();
```

Something makes me think that the problem is in the documentation or in the aws-sdk for Javascript itself. My options are exhausted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is correct. According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RequestSpotLaunchSpecification.html), the `RequestSpotLaunchSpecification` object doesn't have an attribute called `TagSpecifications`.

However, you can tag your Spot Instance request after you create it.

`ec2.requestSpotInstances(params)` returns an array of `SpotInstanceRequest` objects, each containing a `spotInstanceRequestId` (e.g. `sir-012345678`). Use the [CreateTags API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#createTags-property) with these Spot Instance request ids to add the tags.

```
const createTagParams = {
  Resources: [ 'sir-12345678' ], 
  Tags: [
    {
      Key: 'Type', 
      Value: 'Mongo-Dump'
    }
  ]
};
ec2.createTags(createTagParams, function(err, data) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: It worked, but I wish it could be done on requestSpotInstances. There is a bug in aws-sdk javascript, right?

Comment: It's not a bug in the JavaScript SDK. Unfortunately, the Amazon EC2 RequestSpotInstances API itself doesn't accept tags as a parameter. But thanks for the feedback, I will make sure to get it back to the service team.

Comment: @DennisTraub I think what's highly confusing then is that `TagSpecifications` *is* listed as parameter in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#requestSpotInstances-property, in the example code below `Calling the requestSpotInstances operation`.

Comment: Also when we look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/request-spot-instances.html then we see that `--tag-specifications` is a valid command line flag. We should look into the CLI's implementation here to see if and how it includes the tag spec in the same http request that it sends for requesting spot instances.

Comment: @Dr.Jan-PhilipGehrcke I also found this confusing in the documentation.  I think this applies the tag to the SpotInstanceRequest *itself* - when what I was expecting/seeking was a way to tag the instance after creation.